# Article about misuse of statistical method in NYTimes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, statistics-in-media

I am referring to this article: http://www.nytimes.com/2011/01/11/science/11esp.html

> Consider the following experiment. Suppose there was reason to believe that a coin was slightly weighted toward heads. In a test, the coin comes up heads 527 times out of 1,000.
>
> Is this significant evidence that the
>   coin is weighted?
>
> Classical analysis says yes. With a
>   fair coin, the chances of getting 527
>   or more heads in 1,000 flips is less
>   than 1 in 20, or 5 percent, the
>   conventional cutoff. To put it another
>   way: the experiment finds evidence of
>   a weighted coin “with 95 percent
>   confidence.”
>
> Yet many statisticians do not buy it.
>   One in 20 is the probability of
>   getting any number of heads above 526
>   in 1,000 throws. That is, it is the
>   sum of the probability of flipping
>   527, the probability of flipping 528,
>   529 and so on.
>
> But the experiment did not find all of
>   the numbers in that range; it found
>   just one — 527. It is thus more
>   accurate, these experts say, to
>   calculate the probability of getting
>   that one number — 527 — if the coin is
>   weighted, and compare it with the
>   probability of getting the same number
>   if the coin is fair.
>
> Statisticians can show that this ratio
>   cannot be higher than about 4 to 1,
>   according to Paul Speckman, a
>   statistician, who, with Jeff Rouder, a
>   psychologist, provided the example.

**First question:** This is new to me. Has anybody a reference  where I can find the exact calculation and/or can YOU help me by giving me the exact calculation yourself and/or can you point me to some material where I can find similar examples?

> Bayes devised a way to update the
>   probability for a hypothesis as new
>   evidence comes in.
>
> So in evaluating the strength of a
>   given finding, Bayesian (pronounced
>   BAYZ-ee-un) analysis incorporates
>   known probabilities, if available,
>   from outside the study.
>
> It might be called the “Yeah, right”
>   effect. If a study finds that kumquats
>   reduce the risk of heart disease by 90
>   percent, that a treatment cures
>   alcohol addiction in a week, that
>   sensitive parents are twice as likely
>   to give birth to a girl as to a boy,
>   the Bayesian response matches that of
>   the native skeptic: Yeah, right. The
>   study findings are weighed against
>   what is observable out in the world.
>
> In at least one area of medicine —
>   diagnostic screening tests —
>   researchers already use known
>   probabilities to evaluate new
>   findings. For instance, a new
>   lie-detection test may be 90 percent
>   accurate, correctly flagging 9 out of
>   10 liars. But if it is given to a
>   population of 100 people already known
>   to include 10 liars, the test is a lot
>   less impressive.
>
> It correctly identifies 9 of the 10
>   liars and misses one; but it
>   incorrectly identifies 9 of the other
>   90 as lying. Dividing the so-called
>   true positives (9) by the total number
>   of people the test flagged (18) gives
>   an accuracy rate of 50 percent. The
>   “false positives” and “false
>   negatives” depend on the known rates
>   in the population.

**Second question:** How do you exactly judge if a new finding is "real" or not with this method? And: Isn't this as arbitrary as the 5%-barrier because of the use of some preset prior probability?

Comment: For the fair and unfair coins this is a helpful read:
http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/diceRev2.pdf

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I will answer the first question in detail.

> With a fair coin, the chances of
>   getting 527 or more heads in 1,000
>   flips is less than 1 in 20, or 5
>   percent, the conventional cutoff.

For a fair coin the number of heads in 1000 trials follows the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with number of trials $n=1000$ and probability $p=1/2$. The probability of getting more than 527 heads is then

$$P(B(1000,1/2)>=527)$$

This can be calculated with any statistical software package. R gives us

```
> pbinom(526,1000,1/2,lower.tail=FALSE)
   0.04684365
```

So the probability that with fair coin we will get more than 526 heads is approximately 0.047, which is close to 5% cuttoff mentioned in the article.

The following statement

> To put it another way: the experiment
>   finds evidence of a weighted coin
>   “with 95 percent confidence.”

is debatable. I would be reluctant to say it, since 95% confidence can be interpreted in several ways.

Next we turn to

> But the experiment did not find all of
>   the numbers in that range; it found
>   just one — 527. It is thus more
>   accurate, these experts say, to
>   calculate the probability of getting
>   that one number — 527 — if the coin is
>   weighted, and compare it with the
>   probability of getting the same number
>   if the coin is fair.

Here we compare two events $B(1000,1/2)=527$ -- fair coin, and $B(1000,p)=527$ -- weighted coin. Substituting the [formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) for probabilities of these events and noting that the binomial coefficient cancels out we get

$$\frac{P(B(1000,p)=527)}{P(B(1000,1/2)=527)}=\frac{p^{527}(1-p)^{473}}{(1/2)^{1000}}.$$

This is a function of $p$, thus we cand find minima or maxima of it. From the article we may infer that we need maxima:

> Statisticians can show that this ratio
>   cannot be higher than about 4 to 1,
>   according to Paul Speckman, a
>   statistician, who, with Jeff Rouder, a
>   psychologist, provided the example.

To make maximisation easier take logarithm of ratio, calculate the derivative with respect to $p$ and equate it to zero. The solution will be

$$p=\frac{527}{1000}.$$

We can check that it is really a maximum using [second derivative test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative_test) for example. Substituting it to the formula we get

$$\frac{(527/1000)^{527}(473/1000)^{473}}{(1/2)^{1000}}\approx 4.3$$

So the ratio is 4.3 to 1, which agrees with the article.

Comment: "Now maximise this quantity with respect to p": i think you mean minimise.

Comment: @mpiktas (+1) Nice (updated) answer.

Comment: I think this example shows you exactly what a confidence interval is.  I find it easiest to interpret a CI as ONE observation from a Bernouli distributed random variable with a probability parameter equal to the level of confidence.  It only makes sense to me to use CIs if you are doing the experiment repetitively.  Another issue is that what is the alternative hypothesis? is it p=7/10, p>0.5, p=1050/2000? p=527/1000?  Another issue is what do we mean by p=$\frac{1}{2}$? is it EXACTLY $\frac{1}{2}$ or is it $p \in \left(\frac{1}{2} \pm \epsilon \right)$ where $\epsilon$ is a small number.

Comment: @Simon, why is the correction to minimize?

Doesn't value of P found maximize the ratio?

Comment: @statnovice: The original version of the answer had the numerator and denominator switched.